# RecycleView OnItemClickListener is not Working On NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

I Have a navigation drawer which i am trying to get information about what item clicked on the RecycleView.

My DashboardActiviy Layout File:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            style="@style/AppTabLayout"
            app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
            android:minHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabGravity="fill"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.oastudios.motosar.fragments.FragmentDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/nav_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="56dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

My DashboardActivity.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);
        ......
        drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
        drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
    ....
}
```

and Finally my adapters onBindViewHolder:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    NavDrawerItem current = data.get(position);
    holder.bind(data.get(position), listener);
    holder.title.setText(current.getTitle());
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, holder.title.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    holder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(context, holder.title.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I tried exposing textview onClick, or its itemViews onClick but none of them are working for me.

Is there a Z-index issue because i can see my NavigationDrawerAdapter is working and listing my menu elements and sliding in/out properly, nav menu icon is working smoothly but can't get OnClick working.

Please help.

Comment: did you try to put fragment below ViewPager?

Comment: Well, that did the trick... the hell :) Thanks so much!